# LTspice Bode plot is incorrect or inconsistent (op-amp circuit)

Tags: operational-amplifier, ltspice, simulation, bode-plot

I'm testing the open loop transfer function of an op-amp circuit by following this schematic:

[image: Schematic]

This is my LTspice schematic (keep in mind the actual op-amp circuit itself has been thoroughly checked, but if you think there might be a problem feel free to point it out):

[image: LTspice schematic 1]

Finally, this is the Bode plot I obtain (this was run on a new installation of LTSspice and no control panel settings were changed):

[image: Bode plot 1]

As you can see there is a single corner frequency and the gain crossover is not reached before 100 MHz. However, I believe that the correct Bode plot should present twk corner frequencies,  and should drop to 0 dB before 100 MHz. It should look something like this (this was run on a different computer):

[image: Sim and Bode plot 2]

The simulated circuits are identical (except for the wire connecting T10 collector and T9 emitter, which does not produce the second corner frequency), but somehow the plots are different.

UPDATE: I have gone into the standard LTspice library and updated the transistors' capacitances values CJC (Cob) and CJE (Cib) as per the components' datasheets

```
.model 2N2222 NPN(IS=1E-14 VAF=100
+   BF=200 IKF=0.3 XTB=1.5 BR=3
+   CJC=8E-12 CJE=30E-12 TR=100E-9 TF=400E-12
+   ITF=1 VTF=2 XTF=3 RB=10 RC=.3 RE=.2 Vceo=30 Icrating=800m  mfg=NXP)

.model 2N2907 PNP(IS=1E-14 VAF=120
+   BF=250 IKF=0.3 XTB=1.5 BR=3
+   CJC=8E-12 CJE=30E-12 TR=100E-9 TF=400E-12
+   ITF=1 VTF=2 XTF=3 RB=10 RC=.3 RE=.2 Vceo=40 Icrating=600m mfg=NXP)
```

[image: 2N2222 transistor datasheet]
[image: 2N2907 transistor datasheet]

This made no difference to the original simulation and Bode plot. Maybe somebody with a keener eye can notice inconsistencies in the models.

If anybody has any idea as to why this is happening, I would be very glad with your help.

Comment: There has to be circuit differences or, something is different in your LTspice setup between the two computers.

Comment: Maybe there was a capacitor between T10's collector and base for the working version that somehow got removed in error. That's the normal place that internal compensation is placed.

Comment: The capacitor between T10's collector and base is added later as you say. This circuit is explicitly designed to test without compensation.

I edited my original post and add the two circuits next to each other, what kind of settings could change the Bode plot so drastically?

Comment: I'm sorry but despite what you say, there is likely a capacitor in the place I mention when you produced the 2nd AC plot.

Comment: You are speaking about "open-loop" - however, the last diagram shows an RC-feedback resulting in a differentiating block which is close to instability (but this is another point).

Comment: @Andyaka I edited the post and you can now see the second LTSpice simulation & plot next to each other.

Comment: @LvW thank you for your comment but there is no feedback loop as the AC input signal is injected at the non-inverting input of the opamp while the RC network is connected to the inverting input.

Comment: I'm sorry but, I stand by what I say. Maybe T10's model has been tweaked.

Comment: Are the DC operating point currents and voltages same?

Comment: @lostduck, connecting RC network to inverting input is exactly what we call negative feedback. So, you are not measuring open loop TRF. You are measuring closed loop TRF from VIN+ to VOUT. Anyway, this is not relevant to your question. You can ignore it for the moment.

Comment: @sai thank you for your open loop definition clarification! Yes, DC operating point currents and voltages are indeed the same

Comment: The second frequency response shows a gain of 20dB when its phase shift is 180 degrees which will cause oscillation. But the simulation does not show oscillation.

Comment: @Audioguru Actually the transient analysis does show oscillation, the goal later on is to introduce a capacitor across collector and base of T10 to compensate and reduce oscillation but this is beside the problem at hand

Comment: @lostduck, if DC operating point is the same, definitely, the difference is in the capacitance on some net. You can look at the 2 netlists that the tool simulated with and compare instead of looking at the schematics.

Comment: @audioguru, ac simulation is not a very reliable method to reveal oscillations. Even an opamp with resistive POSITIVE feedback will show a magnitude response which looks  as expected for negative feedback.

Comment: I'm confused on what the question is about.  Are we discussing the inner workings of opamp poles or are we trying to figure out the discrepancy of why the same circuit/simulation appears to produce different results on two different PCs?  If it's the latter, I second the notion of comparing the generated netlists.  Or you can edit the question to include a codeblock of the LTspice `.asc` file so others can run your simulation and see which version of the results they get.

Answer (score 1):

> *If anybody has any idea as to why this is happening, I would be very
> glad for your help.*

No matter what you say and how similar the two schematics appear to be, you have a capacitor somewhere (possibly within a modified model) that is introducing a pole at around 1 kHz: -

[image]

At a phase shift of 45° there is a signal attenuation of 3 dB (1 kHz).

The response is so clear in that respect. Just dig a little deeper and you'll find it.

Comment: @Andyaka thank you for your answer! I understand what I'm looking for now. I assume the capacitance is due to the transistors' physics, is it possible that LTSpice does not account for this and can I enable it anywhere?

Comment: Your transistors are much older than simulator programs then maybe they do not have their capacitance listed in their models. Wiring capacitance also must be added.

Comment: @lostduck you need to open the model of the transistors. I'm not sure how you do that in LTspice.

Comment: @Andyaka I have added my transistor model exploration to the original question. Unfortunately it hasn't changed anything

Comment: Why has one of the circuits suddenly changed? The connection from T9 to T10 wasn't on the earlier versions of your question @lostduck also, you need to be comparing the circuit that works pspice models with the circuit that has a different AC characteristic. Nevertheless, there is extra capacitance somewhere that you haven't uncovered.